# FacesConverter fail when id greater than 127?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a primefaces selectOneMenu and it uses a javax.faces.convert.Converter for displaying devices.

It works fine only when the key (device's id) is not greater than 127. When it's greater, after clicking a commandButton the selectOneMenu's arrow becomes red and the commandButton's action is not executed.

Why? Any ideas?

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="deviceActionParameter"
    value="#{sm.ruleConfigureBean.deviceActionParameter}"
    style="width:200px;">
    <f:selectItems value="#{sm.ruleConfigureBean.sensors}"
        var="device" itemLabel="#{device.name}" />
    <f:converter converterId="deviceConverter" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

converter:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "deviceConverter")
public class DeviceConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String key) {
        DeviceDao deviceDao = GuiceSingleton.getInstance().getInstance(
                DeviceDao.class);
        try {
            Device device = deviceDao.getDeviceById(new Long(key)); // this works
            return device;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) {
        if (value != null && value instanceof Device) {
            Device device = (Device) value;
            return "" + device.getIdDevice();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is any exception thrown?

Comment: I smell very hard some `Integer`s being compared with `==`.

Comment: A case of "premature optimization", if you ask me

Comment: Just try to generate log inside converter's catch block.

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki no, any exception is thrown.

Comment: @Jitesh I did, fetching object from database works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's an optimization of Java Integer [caching mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29),

```
        Integer int1=128;
        Integer int2=128;

        if(int1==int2)
            System.out.println("yes");
        else
            System.out.println("no");
```

will show `yes` for Integers in the range `[-128, 127]` and `no` otherwise.
If `equals` is used than it will be `yes` all the time.

Solutions:

- change `getDeviceById()` to use equals
- I believe in later versions it is posible to increase this range
- otherwise stick with Long

Comment: in getDeviceById() ids are compared by mybatis ("=" in SQL query) and it works fine: the proper object is fetched from the database.
and I stick with Long already.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the converter, but in the Device class - I was comparing Longs with ==.

Now it's ok:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Device) {
        return idDevice.equals(((Device) o).getIdDevice());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks for answers :)